# Error getting while installing Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, software-installation

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
virtualbox-qt: Depends: virtualbox (= 4.3.18-dfsg-1) but 4.3.18-dfsg-1 is to be installed
               Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9.1-16ubuntu6 is to be installed
               Depends: libqt4-network (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.8.6+git49-gbc62005+dfsg-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
               Depends: libqt4-opengl (>= 4:4.7.2) but 4:4.8.6+git49-gbc62005+dfsg-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
               Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.6+git49-gbc62005+dfsg-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
               Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.6+git49-gbc62005+dfsg-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
               Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.9.1-16ubuntu6 is to be installed
```

Comment: could you try a `sudo apt-get install -f`,`sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, then try again?

Answer (score 0):

Install synaptic package manager from the software center repository

Open synaptic

Search for and install each dependency

I verified all are available in synaptic